# QML: calling itemAt on Repeater returns null

Tags: qt, qml, repeater

My code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Column {
        Row {
            Repeater {
                id: rectRepeater
                model: 3
                Rectangle {
                    width: 30
                    height: 30
                    color: "red"
                    radius: 10
                }
            }
        }
        Row {
            Repeater {
                model: 3
                Text {
                    text: rectRepeater.itemAt(0).width;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null

I found [this post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/12642/repeater-and-itemat-issue/3) saying that the solution is to use `Component.onCompleted` like this (just inserting a `Component.onCompleted` handler inside the Text object):

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Column {
        Row {
            Repeater {
                id: rectRepeater
                model: 3
                Rectangle {
                    width: 30
                    height: 30
                    color: "red"
                    radius: 10
                }
            }
        }
        Row {
            Repeater {
                model: 3
                Text {
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        text: rectRepeater.itemAt(0).width;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this fails with the same error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

`rectRepeater` items is not exit when you call `itemAt(0)`.

You should call `itemAt` when `rectRepeater` is instantiated.

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    Column {
        Row {
            Repeater {
                id: rectRepeater
                model: 3
                Rectangle {
                    width: 30
                    height: 30
                    color: "red"
                    radius: 10
                }

            }
        }
        Row {
            Repeater {
                id: textrep
                model: 3
                Text {
                    }
            }
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            //Here all object are instantiated
            for (var i = 0; i< textrep.count; i++){
                textrep.itemAt(i).text = rectRepeater.itemAt(0).width
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. So the key is to wait for `onCompleted`. But my own code waits for that signal as well! (see the second code snippet in my question.) So what's the difference?

Comment: In your code `onCompleted` signal applies to `Text` component only. So it emmit when text component is instantiated.
In my code `onCompleted` applied to `Column` component and it emmit when column component and all him childs is instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a conditional binding instead

```
Text {
    text: rectRepeater.count > 0 ? rectRepeater.itemAt(0).width : 0;
}
```

Once the rectRepeater has actually created at least one delegate, the value from that delegate is read.
That works even if the rectRepeater's model becomes empty again at some point or if the item at index 0 changes its width

Comment: Cool, thanks! This is in some ways more elegant than the `onCompleted` solution. You wrote some of the reasons, and also it lets me have the binding code right in the element that it affects, which is very nice. A disadvantage is that it's somewhat verbose (especially as bindings don't support multi-statement binding functions) and it's hard to understand its purpose, necessitating a comment. But all in all, it's the solution I'll use. Note that Konstantin T.'s answer also permits doing a dynamic binding for the width, by assigning a `Qt.binding(...)` expression.

Comment: Hm, I just tested multi-statement binding functions and it turns out they work! This makes your solution an even more attractive one.

Comment: Speculation, did not verify: This might end up setting the text 3 times (in this example), as the repeaters count increases from 0 to 3. Here it is basically irrelevant, but in some other cases it might be heavy enough to matter.

Comment: The binding expression will be evaluated again when the count changes, but the setter of the text property will realize that there was no change, so no unecessary update request for the visualization or any binding that uses that text property as one of its inputs

Comment: Not sure what you mean with mulit-statement bindings, but a binding expression is basically a function and can be arbitratily complex (not that this would necessarily be a good idea).
You could also define a function in rectRepeater that does that and use that function as the binding expression: `text: rectRepeater.firstRectWidth()`

Comment: I have a similar issue (`itemAt` returns `null`, usually for the last item) when I do: `for(var i = 0; i < repeater.count; i++) { repeater.itemAt(i) ... }` not sure if it is a bug or by design (?) Why would `count` be increased before the item is available? The documentation however says that "`itemAt` could return `null` if no item exists at index", and that "The number of items in the model as reported by `count` may differ from the number of created delegates if the Repeater is in the process of instantiating delegates [...]" so in a sense this has to be expected (?).

Comment: So, to comment on this post, it is not correct to only check that `.count` is greater than the index you want to access. You need to explicitly check for `null`.